# Mule 4/DW 2.0: Iterate array inside objects of arrays

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

Here is the sample input JSON:
*

```
[
  {
    "animation_production_studios": [],
    "audio": [
      "English",
      "Japanese"
    ],
    "videos": [
      {
        "DASH": true,
        "aips": [
          400,
          824,
          1191
        ],
      },
      {
        "DASH": true,
        "aips": [
          401,
          825,
          1192
        ],
       }
]
 ]
  },
  {
    "animation_production_studios": ["Studio Chizu"],
    "audio": [
      "English",
      "Japanese"
    ],
    "videos": [
      {
        "DASH": true,
        "aips": [
          403,
          826,
          1193
        ],
      },
      {
        "DASH": true,
        "aips": [
          404,
          827,
          1194
        ],
       }
]
 ]
  }
]
```

*

Here is the expected output (to be able to insert into a db as below):

```
animation_production_studios    audio           videos_dash  videos_aips
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Null                       English, Japanese    true         400, 824, 1191
Null                       English, Japanese    true         401, 825, 1192
Studio Chizu               English, Japanese    true         402, 826, 1193
Studio Chizu               English, Japanese    true         403, 827, 1194
```

Here is the DW%2.0 code I tried:

```
payload map(item, index) -> {
   (item.videos map(viditem, vidindex)) -> {
        videos_aips: (viditem.videos map ((vitem, vindex) -> 
        vitem.aips reduce ((vi, vacc) -> vacc + vi )))[0],
        show_id: item."show_id",
        audio: (payload map ((aitem, aindex) -> item.audio                  
            reduce ((i, acc) -> acc ++ "," ++ i )))[0] 
   }
}
```

---

Throwing an error:

```
(item.videos map(viditem, vidindex)) -> {
                        ^
Invalid input ',', expected ')' for the enclosed expression.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us what you already tried to do and state your question.

Comment: Please check your sample JSON input as it seems it is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see below

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var inputData = read('{
  "data": [
    {
      "animation_production_studios": [],
      "audio": [
        "English",
        "Japanese"
      ],
      "videos": [
        {
          "DASH": true,
          "aips": [
            400,
            824,
            1191
          ]
        },
        {
          "DASH": true,
          "aips": [
            401,
            825,
            1192
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "animation_production_studios": [
        "Studio Chizu"
      ],
      "audio": [
        "English",
        "Japanese"
      ],
      "videos": [
        {
          "DASH": true,
          "aips": [
            403,
            826,
            1193
          ]
        },
        {
          "DASH": true,
          "aips": [
            404,
            827,
            1194
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}', 'application/json')

fun concatArray(objArray=[], separator=",") = 
    if (sizeOf(objArray) == 0) 
        "Null"
    else
        objArray joinBy separator

---
flatten(inputData.data map(item) -> 
  item.videos map (vidItem) -> {
    "animation_production_studios" : concatArray(item.animation_production_studios, ","),
    "audio" : concatArray(item.audio, ","),
    "videos_aips" : concatArray(vidItem.aips, ","),
    "videos_dash" : vidItem.DASH
})
```

This will result to:

```
[
  {
    "animation_production_studios": "Null",
    "audio": "English,Japanese",
    "videos_aips": "400,824,1191",
    "videos_dash": true
  },
  {
    "animation_production_studios": "Null",
    "audio": "English,Japanese",
    "videos_aips": "401,825,1192",
    "videos_dash": true
  },
  {
    "animation_production_studios": "Studio Chizu",
    "audio": "English,Japanese",
    "videos_aips": "403,826,1193",
    "videos_dash": true
  },
  {
    "animation_production_studios": "Studio Chizu",
    "audio": "English,Japanese",
    "videos_aips": "404,827,1194",
    "videos_dash": true
  }
]
```

Note here that I have tried to correct your input to make it valid and put in under "data". Idea here is that you will have outer loop (iterating over parent array) through map and have an inner loop (iterating over videos). There might be a more efficient way to combine the two loops into one. I will update if I find something.